# Which exception handler going to handle the exception if there is no catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

Which exception handler going to handle the exception if there is no catch block ?

```
public class Doubt {

    public static void main(String arg[]) 
     {
        System.out.println("hi");
        int i=10;
        int j;
        try
        {
            j=i/0;//Arithmatic exception type object is created but no catch block  so who will catch d exception..
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("shit");
        }

        System.out.println("program still running");

    }
}
```

Comment: my doubt is, couldn't you have found the answer by running this piece of code instead of asking here?

Comment: i m asking about exception " handler " ,read d question properly pls...

Comment: for every exception an exception type of object is created and someone should hold and handle the exception  object....

Comment: mostly none. your app simply crashes. (in facts, the jvm, the thing that calls your `main` does catch it, but does nothing with it)

Comment: The exception will remain uncaught / unhandled and execution of code will be terminated right after the exception is encountered.

Answer (score 2):

None. The `try..finally` block doesn't catch exceptions at all.
It is used to ensure that the code in the `finally` block gets executed (even when an exception in the `try` block occurs). The `finally` block will always get executed, even when there is a return statement in `try`.

Short from cutting power from your computer or suddenly shutting JVM down (or in some cases interrupting a thread in which the `try` code was executed) there is no way to skip the `finally` block.

Add a catch block to catch an exception:

```
try {
    j=i/0;
} catch(Excecption e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    System.out.println("shit");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of Exceptions in Java:

1. Checked - you are forced to use try catch block, if you do not do that - your program will not compile
2. Unchecked (Runtime Exceptions) - these exception are thrown by jre. As in your example you cannot determine everything at compile time. Instead of your i/0 there could be some number divided by user input. When user passes 0 - you will get runtime exception. Unhandled will crash application.
3. Error - Generally this is almost the same  as above, but this is connected to jvm failures, like memory corruption etc.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM system will catch the exception and crash ungracefully. Add an except statement to either handle the exception or exit gracefully.

Comment: in an interview they asked me this question n gave option    1.defult exception handler   2.uncaught exception handler  3....

Answer (score 0):

Try block

The try block contains set of statements where an exception can occur. A try block is always followed by a catch block, which handles the exception that occurs in associated try block. A try block must be followed by catch blocks or finally block or both.

Catch block

A catch block is where you handle the exceptions, this block must follow the try block. A single try block can have several catch blocks associated with it. You can catch different exceptions in different catch blocks. When an exception occurs in try block, the corresponding catch block that handles that particular exception executes. For example if an arithmetic exception occurs in try block then the statements enclosed in catch block for arithmetic exception executes.

https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/ getsome idea from this..